# how to loop through a list of variable names to use it with the update function from lm

Tags: r, formula, lm

I have a list of variable names that I would like to sequentially exclude from a best fitted model using the function update from lm. Because the list of variables are likely to change I want to loop through a given list but I can not get the elements of the list to be read as dependent variable.
I found some code that I thought it could work:

## Example code

```
hsb2 <-read.csv("www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv")
names(hsb2)
varlist <- names(hsb2)[8:11]
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
lm(substitute(read ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = hsb2)
})
```

But not if I use the update function on a previous lm object

```
words<-c('Age','Sex', 'Residuals')
models <- lapply(words, function(x){update(substitute(
 lmobject,~.-i,list(i = as.name(x))),data =data_complete)})
```

I also tried

```
re<-c()
for (i in 1:3) {
lmt<-update(lmobject,~.-words[i])
r2no_i<-summary(lmt)$r.squared
re<-c(re, r2no_i)
}
```

I think this is pretty simple but I could not make the variable to be read properly
Any tip is highly appreciated

Comment: Where does `lmobject` come from?

Comment: Thanks for reply. lmobject comes from using the stepAIC from MASS package (lm function). lmobject is the object storing the final model chosen using backward method. Now I want to look at the contribution of some variables to the final model. That's when I got stuck. I do not want to rewrite a formula but to use update function to remove the variable of interest from the final model.

Comment: well, then please make sure your example is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) such that all variables are defined. This makes it easier to help you. You can use `update(y~a+b+c+d, ~.-b)` to remove variables from a model but you need that second parameter to be a formula. Something like: `update(y~a+b+c+d, paste0("~.-", "b"))`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the built-in `stats::drop1()` function would do what you need?

Read data (note `"http://..."` is needed)

```
hsb2 <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv")
varlist <- names(hsb2)[8:11]
```

Fit all models: construct list of formulas:

```
formList <- lapply(varlist,reformulate,response="read")
```

Construct models (a little bit of fancy footwork is needed to get the `$call` component to look right)

```
modList <- lapply(formList,
                  function(x) {
                    m <- lm(x,data=hsb2)
                    m$call$formula <- eval(m$call$formula)
                    return(m)
})

words <- c('Age','Sex', 'Residuals')
```

pick one of the fitted models:

```
lmobject <- modList[[1]]
```

construct formulas of the form `. ~ . - w`

```
minus_form <- function(w) 
    reformulate(c(".",paste0("-",w)),response=".")

minus_form("abc")  ## . ~ . + -abc
```

Refit models with dropped terms:

```
newMods <- lapply(words,
                  function(w) {
                     update(lmobject,minus_form(w))
              })
```